# Laravel 5.6 multiple middleware with except on 1 middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 middlewares for my controller, `clearance` & `status`.

I need all the `clearance` middleware on all my controller methods, and for the `status` middleware I need to excpet the following methods: index, create, store and destroy.

I do this in my controller but this applies the except for bot middleware.

```
$this->middleware(['clearance', 'status', ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'store', 'destroy']]]);
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call the middleware function once for each middleware.

```
$this->middleware('clearance');
$this->middleware('status')->except(['index', 'create', 'store', 'destroy']);
```

Comment: This won't override the initial middleware?

Comment: No, all middlewares will be checked in the order you have added them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Middleware Groups:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
*/
protected $middlewareGroups = [
   'web' => [
      \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
      \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
      \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
      \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
      \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
   ],

   'api' => [
      'throttle:60,1',
      'auth:api',
   ],
```

];

Also you can use many middlewares in __construct() method:

```
class UserController extends Controller{
  /**
   * Instantiate a new UserController instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');

    $this->middleware('log', ['only' => [
        'fooAction',
        'barAction',
    ]]);

    $this->middleware('subscribed', ['except' => [
        'fooAction',
        'barAction',
    ]]);
  }
}
```

More: [HTTP Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers), [HTTP Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)